# How to configure SSH client timeout after network failure?

Tags: linux, ssh, tcp

Let's say I connect from a client to a server via SSH, and in the middle of the session I pull the server's network cable. On the client, the ssh connection stays alive for around 15 minutes before failing with a "Broken pipe" message. How can I adjust this timeout? In my case, I need to decrease it so that SSH fails early when there is a network issue.

I found a lot of information on how to avoid disconnections on idle sessions, or have longer connection setup timeouts, but not on the timeout of the established SSH connection itself. I also know there are such timeouts at the TCP level, but I suspect SSH sets up the socket with different values, as TCP timouts are normally around one minute, not the 15 minutes I am observing with SSH.

Client and server are both Ubuntu 14.04 server edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` settings on the client. The maximum time before the client will disconnect is approximately the product of those two.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it. The message that comes out after the timeout is "Timeout, server xxxx not responding.", rather than "Broken pipe".

Comment: I'm getting the same error message :(

Comment: Any solution to this? - getting the same error